Font U/mthrb/m/n/10=mt2hrbt at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. How to fix this?
My MWE is
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[bb=mth]{mathalpha}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{R}$    

\end{document}

And this gives me an error
Font U/mthrb/m/n/10=mt2hrbt at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.

It also points me to the log and that says
FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font mt2hrbt.
FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font mt2hrbt.
FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info: 
FATAL miktex-maketfm - Source: 
FATAL miktex-maketfm - Line: 0


You need the full version (paid) of mtpro2.

The documentation of mathalpha mentions that the option mth will choose
Mathtime Pro 2 Holey Roman.
However, it doesn't tell that this font is part of the full mtpro2 suite, and doesn't appear in the “lite” version, which is free. The full version isn't free.
Thus, unless you buy the full version of mtpro2, you cannot use that option.
